# Memory leak in tomcat7 servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, memory-leaks

I have a problem with a web app running on a tomcat7.

When I try to restart the web app, the port opened by a thread I create inside a servlet is still open.

Only finding and killing the java process helps.

I get this error message in the tomcat log:

> SEVERE: The web application [/mdm-server-1.0.0] appears to have
>   started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer]
>   but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory
>   leak. Nov 26, 2014 1:24:50 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   SEVERE: The web application [/mdm-server-1.0.0] appears to have
>   started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak.

The message seems to lead to a guice problem. I have a Servlet that is supposed to wait for client connections. When the application is re-deployed, the socket remains in use and the java thread survives. 
May it be that the thread holding the socket cannot be stopped since a depencendy, like the guice finalizer, cannot be terminated? Or am I totally on the wrong road there? The class and its dependencies do not use guice but are part of a webapp.

Here is a jstack output, maybe that helps:

> "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed42e2800
>   nid=0x71f1 waiting on condition [0x00007f4ecc68e000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
>       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed4206000
>   nid=0x71f0 runnable [0x00007f4ecc78f000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat]]" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007f4ed4205800 nid=0x71ef waiting on condition
>   [0x00007f4ecc890000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
>   (sleeping)
>       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1508)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "Thread-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ea00f6800 nid=0x71ee runnable
>   [0x00007f4ecc991000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
>       at testproject.server.device.AcceptConnectionDaemon.run(AcceptConnectionDaemon.java:39)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007f4ea074d000 nid=0x71ed in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007f4ecca92000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object
>   monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <0x00000007ea2a9a18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>       - locked <0x00000007ea2a9a18> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:114)
>
> "Thread-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ea1a71800 nid=0x71ec runnable
>   [0x00007f4eccb93000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.epollWait(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.poll(EPollPort.java:194)
>       at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:268)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "pool-1-thread-5" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed42fa000 nid=0x71e9 waiting on
>   condition [0x00007f4ecd41b000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (parking)
>       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>       - parking to wait for  <0x0000000785ed5558> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "pool-1-thread-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed4288800 nid=0x71e8 waiting on
>   condition [0x00007f4ecd51c000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (parking)
>       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>       - parking to wait for  <0x0000000785ed5558> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "pool-1-thread-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4e90001800 nid=0x71e7 waiting on
>   condition [0x00007f4ecd61d000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (parking)
>       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>       - parking to wait for  <0x0000000785ed5558> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "pool-1-thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed42de800 nid=0x71e6 waiting on
>   condition [0x00007f4ecd71e000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (parking)
>       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>       - parking to wait for  <0x0000000785ed5558> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "pool-1-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed42dd800 nid=0x71e5 waiting on
>   condition [0x00007f4ecd81f000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (parking)
>       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>       - parking to wait for  <0x0000000785ed5558> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> "Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed40a7000 nid=0x71e1
>   runnable [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed40a4800 nid=0x71e0
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed40a2000 nid=0x71df
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed409f800
>   nid=0x71de runnable [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007f4ed409c000 nid=0x71dd runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed408f000 nid=0x71dc
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE
>
> "Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed406e800 nid=0x71db in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007f4ece6b5000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>   (on object monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <0x0000000784ccd218> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>       - locked <0x0000000784ccd218> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
>       at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)
>
> "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed406c800 nid=0x71da
>   in Object.wait() [0x00007f4ece7b6000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
>   WAITING (on object monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <0x0000000784cccd80> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>       at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
>       - locked <0x0000000784cccd80> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>
> "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed400d000 nid=0x71d6 in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007f4edacd6000]    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object
>   monitor)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>       - waiting on <0x00000007eb7da230> (a java.lang.Object)
>       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.waitIndefinitely(AbstractRunMojo.java:1357)
>       - locked <0x00000007eb7da230> (a java.lang.Object)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:595)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
>
> "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f4ed4068800 nid=0x71d9 runnable

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking [Thread.isInterrupted()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) in the main loop of your `Daemon` class. Break the loop if it's true and it should allow Tomcat to shutdown your threads successfully.

Comment: I added some more information. isInterrupted is a bool Thread.interrupted now, right? From the java documentation i took the advice to instantly thrown an according exception without success.

Comment: You don't have to throw exception, it should be enough to break out of the loop. You could just make it `while (!interrupted()){...}`. But, on the other hand, I don't think the difference is crucial, so, your problem is probably somewhere else.